# error running _arm_navigation.launch file

Tags: ros, shadow-robot, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
I generated the shadowrobot_arm_navigation package correctly for my shadow robot.
the " planning_components_visualizer.launch" launch file is working. but when I run the "shadowarm_arm_navigation.launch" file I got the following error:

Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
Assimp reports no scene in package://sr_hand/model/meshes/F1.mesh
waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
Robot frame is 'world'
Waiting for robot state ...
Waiting for joint state ...
Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
Waiting for robot state ...
Waiting for joint state ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36505/error--running-_arm_navigation.launch-file/) by [robot_arm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2613/robot_arm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need wto things in place for the arm_navigation.launch file to work - first, you need to make sure that you have are publishing a joint state message with positions and velocities for every joint in your robot.  Then you need to make sure that the controller is up and running, advertising the correct action (control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction), and that you have the correct action name set in the move_arm launch file.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0